# I am using a dragable and resizable selector which is shown on top of my video. I need to get it x and y coordinates according to the video resolution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ffmpeg

I am using @use-gesture/react @react-spring/web to create a draggable and resizable selector over the video. I am also able to get the x and y coordinates of the selector with respect to the video element but since I am giving my video tag height and width so that the video fits my screen the X and Y coordinates I am getting are not in the exact same position in the full resolution video. I need to pass the x and y coordinates to ffmpeg to blur the specific portion of the video.